# Database First Entity Framework Update EDMX but not Model.tt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ef-database-first

I am using entity Database First Entity framework. I have generated my EDMX file in visual studio, as well as the objects (in Model.tt)

I have 1 table (in this example)

```
Users:
Username varchar
Password varchar
Email varchar
```

I then added a new column "LastLoggedIn" in my database via SQL manager. So my table now looks like:

```
Users:
Username varchar
Password varchar
Email varchar
LastLoggedIn DateTime
```

I then clicked on Model.edmx file and ran the Update Model from Database.
The Table was updated in the EDMX diagram, however the code (in the model.tt - users.cs) file did not update.

How do I force the objects to update after the EDMX diagram has been updated?

Comment: Delete the table from the edmx first. Then _update model from database_. You can right click on the _model.tt_ and select _run custom tool_ to generate the code. Also, you need to check if there is any warning after updating the edmx models from database.

Comment: you have to make sure when you update you also click save to save the model when you click save it will update the files.

Comment: thanks. this worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF can be a bit of a pain at times, and doesn't like to update.  For tables, when this happens, delete the table from the diagram.  Then save it.  Then do a right click and choose to Update the edmx.  This should add the updated table with the new column.